# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split') when running code coverage istanbul

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, istanbul

I have a Vue project and whenever I try to do a test coverage I run into the following error; `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')`. I have tested it on 0.34.1, 0.34.6 and 1.0.1... The culprit which causes the error would be in the file: `removeQueryParameters node_modules/@vitest/coverage-istanbul/dist/provider.js:294:19`

```
function removeQueryParameters(filename) {
  return filename.split("?")[0];
}
```

I could resolve this by putting an `if` statement around the return, but am rather curious whether there is a version of istanbul which doesn't have this bug (yet), or whether I could have possibly misonfigured settings and merely suppressing the "error" by using the `if` statement.

My env:

```
"nuxt": "^3.7.3",
"nuxt-vite": "^0.3.5",
"nuxt-vitest": "^0.10.5",
"@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
```

Comment: Seems like your 'filename' is undefined.

Comment: @nanodev I understand. I am curious whether other people are also experiencing the same or that it's simply me. I am also rather curious as to why such a check hasn't been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` operator after filename. So it will check if file name exists before going to `split()[0]`

```
function removeQueryParameters(filename) {
  return filename?.split("?")[0];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I am bound to using version control of istanbul... Therefore I am checking whether there is a version which didn't have this bug yet. I have already opened an issue on their github page as well to verify whether this is a known bug (and whether they can resolve it).

Comment: Best is to use above mentioned approach and unblock yourself and move ahead. Appreciate if you could provide an upvote for the answer. Assume the if the fix you are looking for might come or might not

Comment: I know it's best, but I need to verify whether this is a known problem which can be resolved by upgrading/downgrading or that I have no other option besides implementing this.